# AWS RDS "Maintenance Required"

Tags: amazon-rds, aws, maintenance

I saw from the web interface that maintenance on my RDS postgresql instances is required, so I ran `aws rds describe-pending-maintenance-actions`, and it says that there's a "system-update" because "New Operating System update is available".

That's fine, so I restarted the instances 90 minutes ago (`aws rds stop-db-instance` then `aws rds start-db-instance`).

90+ minutes later, the instances are still "Maintenance Required".

What did I do wrong, or not do?  Or is this just a notification that AWS is going to be doing something that's outside of my control?

```
$ aws rds describe-pending-maintenance-actions --output=table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                            DescribePendingMaintenanceActions                            |
||                               PendingMaintenanceActions                               ||
|+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+|
||  ResourceIdentifier |  arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:xxxxxxxxxxxx     ||
|+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+|
|||                           PendingMaintenanceActionDetails                           |||
||+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+||
|||  Action                     |  system-update                                        |||
|||  AutoAppliedAfterDate       |  2022-06-30T00:00:00+00:00                            |||
|||  CurrentApplyDate           |  2022-06-30T00:00:00+00:00                            |||
|||  Description                |  New Operating System update is available             |||
|||  ForcedApplyDate            |  2022-10-30T00:00:00+00:00                            |||
||+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+||
||                               PendingMaintenanceActions                               ||
|+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+|
||  ResourceIdentifier |  arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:yyyyyyyyyyyyy   ||
|+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+|
|||                           PendingMaintenanceActionDetails                           |||
||+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+||
|||  Action                     |  system-update                                        |||
|||  AutoAppliedAfterDate       |  2022-06-30T00:00:00+00:00                            |||
|||  CurrentApplyDate           |  2022-06-30T00:00:00+00:00                            |||
|||  Description                |  New Operating System update is available             |||
|||  ForcedApplyDate            |  2022-10-30T00:00:00+00:00                            |||
||+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+||
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Maintenance.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.OSUpgrades) says you should be able to trigger the upgrade by choosing the instance that you want to apply the upgrade to and select “Maintenance and Backup” tab followed by selecting the pending maintenance and clicking “Apply Now”

￼
[image: Apply Upgrade]